# Express + Typescript: How to GET Param and Body request

Tags: typescript, express

I route put method to this

```
const createFaceList = (req: Request<{faceListId : string}>, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

console.log(req.body.name);
console.log("faceListID = " + req.params.faceListId);

addFacelist(req.params.faceListId, req.body)
.then( result => {
    return res.status(200).json({result})
})
.catch(err => {
    logging.error(NAMESPACE, err.messagem, err);

    return res.status(err.statusCode).json({
        statusCode: err.statusCode,
        message: err.message
    })
})
}
```

my console.log show that undefined:

```
undefined
faceListId = undefined
```

how to fix.
thank you

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You haven't shown us the route which would define `params`. You haven't shown us the body parsing middleware that would define `body`. You haven't shown us the request, which provides the data to populate both with.

Comment: I'm so apologize, I'm newbie for typescript. I try it in post man. I didn't define them.
this my request URL: `localhost:1337/faceapi/put/addFacelist?faceListId=sampleid-111`

Comment: this is a Parse the request:
`router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
router.use(bodyParser.json());`

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface TypedRequestBodyParams<Params, ReqBody> extends Express.Request {
    body: ReqBody,
    params: Params
}

const createFaceList = (req: TypedRequestBodyParams<{faceListId : string}, {name: string}>, res: Response) => {
    const { faceListId } = req.params
    const { name } = req.body
}
```